# C : fscanf called multiple times does not work

Tags: c, scanf

I try to read differents values in a text file : 
here's my file :

```
4,3
30.0
20.0
1.0
```

My output works for the first line, I can get 4 and 3 separately by one fscanf call. But then when I want to call again fscanf to get double, it returns 0 but I want 30.0 !

My code is here :

```
int* read_size(FILE* f) {
  int*  taille;
  fscanf(f, "%d,%d", &taille[0], &taille[1]);
  return taille;
}

int read_int(FILE* f) {
  int i;
  fscanf(f, "%d", &i);
  return i;
}

double read_double(FILE* f) {
  double d;
  fscanf(f, "%lf", &d);
  return d;
}

FILE* getFile() {
  char* fileName = "1.conf";
  FILE* f = fopen(fileName, "r");
  return f;
}



 int main( int argc, char *argv[]) {
      FILE* f = getFile();
      int* taille = read_size(f);
      printf("maitre : taille[0] : %d, taille[1] : %d\n", taille[0], taille[1]);
      double temperature = read_double(f);
      printf("maitre : lecture de temperature %2f\n", temperature);  
}
```

Comment: `int*  taille;` is an unitialised pointer - trying to read into it is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int*  taille;` reserves space for a pointer, but not for the actual values.
Reading in values to where the pointer arbitrarily points to, yields undefined behaviour.

The easiest way to fix this is to write `static int taille[2]` instead.
Then the rest should work fine.

Comment: Fixes like that may be "easiest", but not exactly "best".